# Every claim from Windows ID comes back as the same thing

Tags: azure, access-control

I am experimenting with using the Access Control Service in Azure. I have most of it working, I can log in using any of the providers but I'm having an issue with the claims against the WindowsLive provider. With the google provider I am able to get such useful information as the person's name and their e-mail address. I put similar claims in for WindowsLive but I get back the same value for every single claim. I've tried

- http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier (I expected this to be gobbildygook)
- http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/EmailAddress
- http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/CommonName
- http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress
- http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name

each of these return something like :oULpbTv2AMylPasgUOsLZAHjaBYtxldrU+gg3aS5nI4=

Now I'm pretty sure that isn't my e-mail address because it wouldn't fit on my business card and I know it isn't my name because my mother isn't Welsh and wouldn't support me being named as if I were.

I followed the tutorials found at http://robbincremers.me/2012/02/22/using-windows-azure-access-control-service-to-provide-a-single-sign-on-experience-with-popular-identity-providers/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185914.aspx to get this set up.

Is there some way that I can get information other than an identifier out of WindowsLive? Maybe the issue is related to my not setting up an encryption certificate?

**Edit:** After some searching I found [Are any other claims available from Windows Live ID via the ACS 2.0 identity provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391406/are-any-other-claims-available-from-windows-live-id-via-the-acs-2-0-identity-pro) which suggests that my attempts to get more information out of WindowsLiveID is a hopeless quest. I will just prompt users for information when they log in for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The windows live provider doesn't give you anything other than a unique providerId.  This is unique to your application and the user's windows live id.  Google is a little better in that they give you the users name as well as their email.

The way I solved this is that on account creation in my application I just collect any information from the user that I need in addition to what is provided from the claims.  So if they are using Google then i pre-populate their Email and name on my "Create Account" form.  If they're using Windows then the form fields are just blank and they have to fill out the necessary info to finish creating their account.  It works pretty well.

Comment: Prepopulating is a good idea, I hadn't thought of that. Thanks!